# Javascript variable/string functions?

Tags: javascript, string, function

I am practicing code readability and "beautifying" my code, so I want to learn how to implement this.

I've seen other code do this, but I don't remember which or how they did it.

I want to create my own .string functions, like so:

```
var rmbrackets = new function() {
  return String.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "");
}
console.log("this is a [test]test!".rmbrackets);
```

I want the above to log "this is a test!".
The above is just an example, I want to do this with many other functions.

How can i do this?

Comment: In JavaScript, you have to put parens on when invoking a function `"foo".rmbrackets()`, unlike Ruby. Without the parens, you are grabbing the reference to the function instead.

Comment: I found out. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
String.prototype.rmbrackets = function() {
  return this.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "");
};
```

This adds to the Object String's prototype.

Also, you'll need to add `()` to actually execute it, so the full code would be

```
String.prototype.rmbrackets = function() {
  return this.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, "");
};
console.log("this is a (test)test!".rmbrackets());
```

In this example I edited your regex to match what you want to achieve.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8TWGK/)

---

If you agree with **Matt Greer,** then you could just create a function for this:

```
function rmbrackets(text)
{
  return text.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, "");
};
console.log(rmbrackets("this is a (test)test!"));
```

Because *if everyone did this, built in prototypes would get polluted pretty quickly. People would step over each other a lot. There is also the problem if browsers natively added a rmbrackets, you might shadow it. Other problems include unexpected properties showing up in for in loops and such. In general, the JS community has agreed to leave built in prototypes alone.*

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8TWGK/3/)

Comment: Just keep in mind altering global prototypes is pretty well shunned. Probably best to not do this if you intend your code to be used by others.

Comment: Oh, ok. Why though? Does this affect execution or loading speeds?

Comment: @MattGreer I don't understand why, could you explain?

Comment: @JacobPedersen if everyone did this, built in prototypes would get polluted pretty quickly. People would step over each other a lot. There is also the problem if browsers natively added a `rmbrackets`, you might shadow it. Other problems include unexpected properties showing up in `for in` loops and such. In general, the JS community has agreed to leave built in prototypes alone.

Comment: Alright, i guess i should not use this. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 1):

Well... you can modify the prototype property to add new functionality:

```
String.prototype.sayHello = function(){
   return this + " Hello!";
}

"Blah".sayHello(); // "Blah Hello!"
```

Comment: You have some slight syntax issues, other than that this is pretty much what the OP wants

Comment: @MattGreer - Yeah, just now saw that. Typed in a hurry :)